# How should I write a simple installer for python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, package

I'm writing a simple python package with many helper functions to be used with other projects.
How should handle I packaging and make installer for said package?

## Directory layout

**package:**

```
package (/git/dev/package)
 |
 +-- __init__.py
 |
 +-- foo.py
 |
 +-- bar.py
```

**project using said package:**

```
project (/git/dev/project)
 |
 +-- project.py
```

How do I make this package available to every local python project (I don't need to distribute it publicly)? Should installer add current package location to path or use some other way?

Current preferred workflow:

```
1. checkout package from version control
2. do something so python finds and can use that said package
3. use package in some project
4. edit package (project should use edited package even before I push those changes to repo)
```

## File contents

**project.py:**

```
# Doesn't work currently since package isn't added to path
from package import foo
from package import bar

foo.do_stuff()
bar.do_things()
```

Comment: What platform are you targeting specifically?

Comment: @ham-sandwich using windows as dev platform. Every developer has more or less similar system, but package location differs

Comment: Your second question is completely separate from your first one, so you should ask it as a separate question. But the short answer is that you should never just do `import bar`; either use an absolute import like `from package import bar`, or an explicit relative import like `from . import bar`, not an implicit relative import like `import bar`. (Especially in Python 3, where implicit relative imports don't even work anymore.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make this package available to every python project?

The standard way to distribute packages is as source distributions on PyPI (or a private `pip`-compatible repository). The details take up many pages, so I can't explain them all here, but the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/) has everything you want to know.

The basic idea is that you create a `setup.py` file that tells Python how to install your program. Look at [the official sample linked from the tutorial](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py).

Now, someone can just download and unzip your package and run `python setup.py install` and it will install your program for them. Or, better, they can type `pip install .`.

But, even better, you can `python setup.py sdist` to create a source distribution, test it out, upload it to PyPI, and then users don't have to download anything, they can just `pip install mylib`.

If you want binary installations for different platforms, `setuptools` knows how to make both Windows installers, which can be double-clicked and run, and `wheel` files, which can be installed with `pip` (in fact, it'll automatically find and use wheels instead of source distributions). If you don't have any compiled C extensions, `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` is enough to build a wheel that works everywhere.

---

> Should installer add current package location to path or use some other way?

The installer should install the package into the user's system or user (or current-virtual-environment-system) site-packages. If you use `setuptools`, `pip` will take care of this automatically.

---

If you're not trying to make this public, you can still use `setuptools` and `pip`. Just check the source distribution into source control, then you can install the latest version at any time like this:

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/mycompany/mylib
```

This also means you can skip a lot of the PyPI metadata in your setup.py file (e.g., nobody cares about your project's classifiers if it's not going to end up in the PyPI repository).

But you can still take advantage of all of the parts of the Python packaging system that make your life easier, while skipping the parts that aren't relevant.

Comment: preferred use case: checkout newest package, run install, and whenever you want to update you just pull newest version of said package

Comment: But what if I wanted that project uses package version that is currently checked out from version control, without need to upgrade every time I do some changes?

Comment: @KlausHelenius: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to not get the changes even though there's a newer version? To not see your changes until you check them in? To somehow get someone else's changes without even checking them out? …?

Comment: @abarnett I mean that when I'm locally working with a project and do edits to package, project should use those edited files without me needing to push those changes to repo and do an upgrade. For example if I add "sys.path.append(PATH_TO_PACKAGE)" to a project, it uses package files that I'm currently working with. And after every small change I do to package, I don't need to push my changes to repo and do an upgrade. (I don't want workflow to be: 1) edit package, 2) push changes to repo, 3) upgrade package, 4) use package in project) Or did I misunderstand how "pip install --upgrade" work?

Comment: @KlausHelenius: Well, you an `pip install --upgrade .` to solve that. But it sounds like what you really want isn't a package at all, but something like a git submodule, which acts like an inherent part of each program rather than a separate package, but which is shared by all of them? If so, the best answer probably depends on which VCS you're using. (As you can guess, with git, the answer is git submodule, but with, say, svn, the answer involves a lot of pulling out of hair and banging your head on the desk…)

Comment: I'm using git. So instead putting helper functions shared by multiple projects to their own package, I should turn it into a git submodule? Can you give me any directions how should I turn that package into submodule and add it to the projects using it? Or should I just make new separate question for it?

Comment: @KlausHelenius: If what you want is to be able to treat the package as if it were an inherent part of each project, and for each project's developers to be able to edit it as if it were part of their own project, then yes, I think a git submodule is the answer. (And if you read the docs on git submodule and get stuck, then make a new question.) But if you're just looking to be able to multitask, going back and forth between editing the package and an app that uses it without having to create branches all over the place, you may still want to use a package and just `pip install .` from in-tree.